# How to stub a method from a module in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

`lib/modules/api.rb`:

```
module Api
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

  def send_get_request(url, body)
    # some logic
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  include Api

  def index
    response = send_get_request(_some_, _params_)[:json]
    @something = response['something']
  end
end
```

How do I stub the `send_get_request` method? I tried a feature test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'visiting users page' 
  it 'shows users page' do
    visit '/'
    allow_any_instance_of(Api).to receive(:send_get_request).with(any_args).and_return({json: {'total_paying' => '3'}})
    within('#side-menu') do
      click_link 'Users'
    end
    expect(page).to have_selector('.page-header', text: 'Users')
  end
end
```

but apparently it doesn't work (the test fails because real `send_get_request` method gets called with params that are incorrect (which they are in tests).

When I tried

```
expect_any_instance_of(Api).to receive(:send_get_request).once
```

That expectation passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's the controller that will receive the message. The test, as a client, does not care about how the method is defined, "normally" or mixed-in.

If it were a controller spec, you'd be able to do this:

```
 allow(controller).to receive(:send_get_request).with(...)
```

As for the feature specs, don't stub anything in there. It's supposed to be the "real" interaction. In feature specs you use capybara (or something) to fill the forms and then check the database (to see if a user got created, etc.)

To shield your feature specs from external api, you can use [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). It basically runs your external query one time, writes the response into a file and then, on subsequent runs, just plays it back, without contacting external api again.

Comment: `allow(DashboardController).to receive(:send_get_request).with(any_args).and_return({json: {'total_paying' => '3'}})` throws `DashboardController does not implement: send_get_request`

Comment: In controller specs, the name `controller` resolves to instance of controller under test. This doesn't work in feature specs. See my updated answer.

Comment: How should I then test "real" interaction in feature tests if all the data displayed for the user comes from an external API? I want to test whether user gets redirected to a proper page after clicking on a link.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I used webmock as final solution. :)